# Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7-beta2

I'm currently developing my first iOS app using Swift 2.0 and Xcode Beta 2. It reads an external JSON and generates a list in a table view with the data. However, I'm getting a strange little error that I can't seem to fix:

```
Extra argument 'error' in call
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Task completed")

            if(error != nil){
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

            var err: NSError?

            if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary{

                if(err != nil){
                    print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }

                if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.tableData = results
                        self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

The error is thrown at this line:

```
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary{
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This line doesn't giving this error i think may b you are getting in different line.

Comment: With 2.0 you need to create a `do` `catch` block. `error` is no longer a parameter with `NSJSONSerialization`. There are a number of other answers to this question here. Look for do, catch with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 75, accepted):

With **Swift 2**, the *signature* for `NSJSONSerialization` has changed, to conform to the new error handling system.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        print(jsonResult)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

With **Swift 3**, the *name* of `NSJSONSerialization` and its methods have changed, according to [the Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/).

Here's the same example:

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print(jsonResult)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I am using swift 2.2, and tried your first version.  It is compiling correctly but it is dying silently, does not hit either of the the `print` lines.  When I remove the `if` part in front of `jsonResult` and run I can infer that the jsonResult is being set as `nil` no errors.  I am sure the data starts as a valid json string...

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Your JSON is probably different from what you think. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33510776/2227743

Comment: Thanks, yes that was it!  Replacing `as? NSDictionary` with `as? NSArray` in your first example works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Things have changed in Swift 2, methods that accepted an `error` parameter were transformed into methods that throw that error instead of returning it via an `inout` parameter.  By looking at the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:):

> HANDLING ERRORS IN SWIFT:
>   In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.
>
> You call this method in a try expression and handle any errors in the catch clauses of a do statement, as described in Error Handling in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1) and Error Handling in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.1).

The shortest solution would be to use `try?` which returns `nil` if an error occurs:

```
let message = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options:.AllowFragments)
if let dict = message as? NSDictionary {
    // ... process the data
}
```

If you're also interested into the error, you can use a `do/catch`:

```
do {
    let message = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options:.AllowFragments)
    if let dict = message as? NSDictionary {
        // ... process the data
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("An error occurred: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed in Swift 3.0.

```
 do{
            if let responseObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: results, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{

                if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(responseObj){
                    //Do your stuff here
                }
                else{
                    //Handle error
                }
            }
            else{
                //Do your stuff here
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
                print("An error occurred: \(error)") }
```