# Swift 2 Extra argument ' error' in call

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

Hi i'm updating my project from Swift to Swift2 with Xcode 7 and i'm getting this CoreData error :

```
Extra argument 'error' in call
```

in this line

```
if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
```

**EDIT**

this is my code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Xipe_Tech.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

        do {
            try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }

        return coordinator
    }()
```

now i get error in first line
how can i fix that ??
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call)

Answer (score 13):

Swift 2 now provides a try/catch mechanism, and Cocoa APIs have been rewritten to use this instead rather than returning the error the traditional Objective C way.

You should now do this:

```
do {
    try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)

}
```

Comment: now i get error in this line : ` lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {` the error is: `Call can throw, but is not marked as try and the error is not handling`

Comment: Please show your code. But it seems like your are not adding the try annotation before calling the function

Comment: Instead of just changing your code, you might consider watching the WWDC videos and actually learning what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

anyone else having this issue just use this below. I had the same issue. Apple replaced the original "if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType" with a do try catch phrase.

```
do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()
```