# Arguments passed to call that takes no arguments - error in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

The error is on two line I have marked it by `//`

The first error is - `extra argument 'error' in call`

The second error is - `argument passed to that call takes no arguments`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.ShreyasPapinwar.Shreyas_Papinwar" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] 
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Shreyas_Papinwar", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Shreyas_Papinwar.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

// -------> this line has error - extra argument error in call
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 Extra argument ' error' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113479/swift-2-extra-argument-error-in-call)

Comment: Take a look at the [api docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs:

```
func addPersistentStoreWithType(_ storeType: String,
                  configuration configuration: String?,
                            URL storeURL: NSURL?,
                        options options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) throws -> NSPersistentStore
```

Meaning -> this function's signature has no error parameter at its end! In case of error it throws an exception:

From the docs:

> HANDLING ERRORS IN SWIFT:
>   In Swift, this method returns a nonoptional result and is marked with the throws keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this:

- Create a new sample project with Core Data enabled in Xcode 7 / Swift 2
- Copy and paste the Core Data stack code from the sample project into yours.
  There are a few more changes in Swift 2.
- Adjust file name, data model name and other custom settings.

Nevertheless – as luk2302 suggests - read the docs!