# Extra argument 'error' in call. Compilation error in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am currently trying to learn about Swift 2.0 and OAuth integration via this sample application: https://github.com/soundcloud/iOSOAuthDemo

The following snippet below is causing me problems and causing the application to fail in its compilation.

```
private func requestMe(token: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.soundcloud.com/me.json?oauth_token=\(token)")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
                               delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonOutput = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
            self.displayMe(jsonOutput)
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

However when compiling my error handling looks as though it has changed in this version of Swift (2.0) and is causing the following error:

> Extra argument 'error' in call with the compilation.

I have reviewed the following stack posting on this issue: [Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call)

and adjusted my code to try and correct the error handling as such:

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonOutput = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
            self.displayMe(jsonOutput)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error);}
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

I have also tried changing:

```
(data, options: nil, error: nil)
```

to

```
(data:NSData?, error:NSError?)
```

However neither of these resolving the issue. Can someone guide me as to what is probably a silly mistake I am making with this error handling.

Thanks in advance!,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several problems with your code: you added `catch` but forgot `do` and `try`. Also you can't pass `nil` as an option parameter anymore for NSJSONSerialization, and you have to safely unwrap the `data` optional.

Here's a fixed version:

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {
        if let myData = data, let jsonOutput = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] {
            self.displayMe(jsonOutput)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Thanking you kindly Eric D!