# iOS: JSONObjectWithData

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I updated Xcode to version 7 and tried reusing my old code:

```
let downloadTask : NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(dataURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)
let dataDictionary : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
})
```

On the last line I'm now getting error: *Extra argument 'error' in call*

Though in the NSJSONSerialization Class reference the method contains the error argument.

I'm still kinda newbie in this, if someone can please explain me what's going on and how to solve this I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)
do {
    let dataDictionary : NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: []) as NSDictionary
} catch _ {
    dataObject = nil
}
```