# json Authentication using swift 2.0

Tags: ios

how to authenticate the `json` method in `swift`?

```
var error: NSError?
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470527/swfit-2-extra-argument-error-in-call/33470805#33470805

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
do {
       let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

   } 
catch 
{
     print("error")
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: NSError not available in swift 2.0 can you modify your answer is useful

Comment: no bro its wrong , check this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470527/swfit-2-extra-argument-error-in-call/33470805#33470805

Comment: its not important, i have used the code, catch statement is empty, but its working fine

Comment: if you write this code in swift 2.0, its working fine