# How to create dictionary from JSON

Tags: swift

I receive JSON objects that looks like the one below. How can I convert it into a format that is easily handled by Swift 2.1 ? I will receive several of these and have to put them into an array and sort by createdAt.

```
Optional({
    comment = "<null>";
    completedAt = "<null>";
    createdAt = "2015-11-02 15:01:04 +0000";
    paid = 1;
    paidAt = "2015-11-02 15:01:04 +0000";
    startedAt = "<null>";
    state = request;
    type = doctor;
    user = KTsCySacEAiz3eDnf;
    userdata =     {
        birthdate = "<null>";
        gender = "<null>";
    };
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call)

Comment: Simple example for you in my linked answer.

Comment: Hi, I looked at that, it gives me [_] is not convertible to NSJSONReadingOptions

Comment: Hmm, I have version 2.1
Apple Swift version 2.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.6 clang-700.1.76)

Comment: How did you get the Optional you're showing in your question? Could you show this piece of code? We could try to adapt it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I gave up, just put all the individual fields into arrays instead - Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As in the title you say you expect a Dictionary, you can get one by simply serializate the json and cast it to a Dictionary.

```
do{
     let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
}catch{
     print("Something went wrong")
}
```

Where data is you json content as NSData. If you get a String you can easily convert it

```
let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Where data is you json content" mean?

Comment: I now get 'Extra argument 'error' in call',...  Are you sure this is swift 2.0 ?

Comment: You change to 2.0 while writing the answer. Your code should look something like that.  Swift 2.0 changed the way Error Handling must be done: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch