# Swift 2 parse Json as Optional to array

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am getting list of countries from a web service. After receiving it I used this code to process it:

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
    // triggering callback function that should be processed in the call
    // doing logic
} else {
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? AnyObject {
       completion(json)
    } else {
       let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)                          
       print("Error could not parse JSON string: \(jsonStr)")
    }
}
```

And after that list looks like this (it ends up in this part `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? AnyObject`) :

```
 Optional((
            {
            "country_code" = AF;
            "dial_code" = 93;
            id = 1;
            name = Afghanistan;
        },
            {
            "country_code" = DZ;
            "dial_code" = 213;
            id = 3;
            name = Algeria;
        },
            {
            "country_code" = AD;
            "dial_code" = 376;
            id = 4;
            name = Andorra;
        }
))
```

I should now convert this json object to array (or NSDictionary somehow) and to loop through it. Can someone advice how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you can't loop through your object because it has been cast as `AnyObject` by your code. With your current code you're casting the JSON data either `as? NSDictionary` or `as? AnyObject`.

But since JSON always start with a dictionary or an array, you should do this instead (keeping your example):

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
    // process "json" as a dictionary
} else if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? NSArray {
    // process "json" as an array
} else {
    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)                          
    print("Error could not parse JSON string: \(jsonStr)")
}
```

And ideally you would use Swift dictionaries and arrays instead of Foundation's NSDictionary and NSArray, but that is up to you.

Comment: I will test it and accept this answer if it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

Comment: Still the same, not working (I have added it to `if` clause)