# Error in countForFetchRequest in swift 2.3 migration

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I migrated my code to swift 2.3 which resulted in "Extra argument 'error' in call" for the line:

```
var count:Int = moc.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
```

So, I found to handle it with try catch from: [Swift: Extra argument 'error' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073497/swift-extra-argument-error-in-call), and put it inside try catch as follows:

```
var count:Int = 0

do {
    count = try moc.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    return count
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return count
}
```

Now its showing error on returning count. Error is: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'int' to return type 'NSArray' ". Couldn't figure out the new syntax error. Please help.

Comment: Look into the documentation of `NSManagedObjectContext` or retype the line and use code completion

Comment: What does the `func` declaration for this method look like?